# How malware triggers without user running an executable?

Tags: exploit, virus

It is known that downloading a file without actually executing it can be a security vulnerability, if the operating system does something which is not known by the user. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/94356) for some good answers.

However, I could not find a detailed explanation on how some of those things are done. Suppose that after downloading a file, the OS triggers some process to scan the files, for "antivirus" or "thumbnails", and the file utilises the vulnerability of the process scanning it to execute arbitrary code. My question is, how can arbitrary code which has never been written into the vulnerable scanner process suddenly be injected into it?

Let's assume the buggy process is written in C. For most C programs, all memory allocated are not executable, so injecting code into it does not have any security issues. Therefore, only a small collection of C programs which implements something like a JIT compiler inside and **actively allocates executable memory** can have such vulnerability. This seems to exclude thumbnail generators written in C, since there is no reason to use JIT in C for thumbnails. Moreover, executable memory should be readonly if handled properly (and in fact, this is a mandatory requirement on many systems, for programs with JIT inside to run at all), and the typical practice is to lock executable memory when you are not editing it. This insulates the possibility of injecting code, even if memory is used incorrectly by mistake. Finally, even if all those protection fails, and the file-scanning process does modify executable memory in an unintended way, how can it possibly be made to do it in the way the malware wants? After all, it is a bug, so it is usually something unpredictable. I just could not imagine how a bug can cause a program to load code byte-by-byte from a file **in its entirety and accurately,** unless one is intentionally doing this.

Could anyone explain (possibly with examples) how a bug can cause a program to have such probabilistically unlikely behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I'll use CVE-2023-4836 as an example. This is a vulnerability in Google's WebP image format using a buffer overflow attack. The image parsing library in `libwebp` is the core of CVE-2023-4836.

WebP uses something called Huffman tables for compression and the vulnerability revolves around how `libwebp` deals with memory allocation in relation to the Huffman tables. Basically a specifically crafted image can lead to a overflow of the buffer allocated to the Huffman table (I don't understand the Huffman table algorithm well enough but there are some hard coded table sizes in `libwebp`). The specifically crafted image would be something that says I'm a 10000x10000 image (or whatever size you want to overflow the buffer) but only a 10 byte image is included and the rest of the space is used for malicious code. Therefore to the casual observer the image acts as intended thereby not raising any red flags.

This means that the malicious code has now overflowed the buffer and has overwritten other information in the WebP image parser's heap. By knowing the exact size of the buffer for the Huffman table (which in the case of `libwebp` was hardcoded) attackers can add enough 'padding' to fill the buffer with useless data, then start the actual malicious payload after that knowing it will now be written to the heap.

Comment: The question is, how people execute the payload after writing it to memory?

Comment: The parent executable is already running (parsing the image in this case) but instead of running it's intended code, it is now running the code new malicious code instead. EDIT: for example say there is a function that does some arithmetic, my payload overwrites that with say a reverse shell. When the function calls happens instead of the arithmetic happening it opens a reverse shell

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But isn't the memory pages for codes read-only on many systems? Overwriting that will simply segfault or something?

Comment: You are right, my comment was a bit of an oversimplification. The Code segment is usually read only, but the Heap segment is by necessity writeable because it is dynamic. The heap buffer overflow occurs in the heap (as the name implies) where our overflow can overwrite other information in the heap. Functions that use data from the heap are now vulnerable depending on how they interact with that data. When writing a function we are expecting it to deal with some specific data thus we will not put in layers upon layers of protections on each function to deal with sometimes unforeseeable data.

Comment: This is a video explaining a stack buffer overflow (not a heap buffer overflow as the one described above)w hich might be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZTilLGAcFQ

Answer (score 1):

Attacks don't need malicious code, often they can trigger existing code with malicious parameters (write this string to a file with this path becomes *very* dangerous if you allow an attacker to choose both the path and content).

Subclasses of this sort of attack are

- return-to-libc (a buffer overflow of a local variable can overwrite the return address)
- vtable modification (a buffer overflow of a heap variable can overwrite the object header of a neighboring allocation)

Neither stacked return addresses nor function pointers in vtables are "executable", so W^X protections don't help.